# fullname(firstname+" "+lastname) in dropdownlist in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, dropdownlistfor

I'm confuse to con-cat Firstname and Lastname and show list in Dropdownlist.
I have this in my model

```
 public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return Firstname+ " " + Lastname ;
        }
    }
```

In view I want FullName to show in dropdownlist or listbox
I try below code in view but has error:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("FullName", String.Empty)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.tbl_hamyaran.FullName)
```

error:There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'FullName'.

**I got my answer.**

**I just need to change this line in my controller:**

```
     ViewBag.sabtkonande_ID = new SelectList(db.tbl_hamyaran, "ID", "Name");

to line:

  ViewBag.sabtkonande_ID = new SelectList(db.tbl_hamyaran, "ID", "FullName");
```

Comment: whats the confusion? question is not clear

Comment: How are you generating the dropdownlist. What is it actually displaying. You need to explain your problem

Comment: i dont know how show fullname in dropdownlist

Comment: You need to create a `SelectList` in the controller and use that in he `DropDownList` helper. There are hundreds of thousands of examples of how to use `DropDownList()` and `DropDownListFor()` on the web.

Comment: @ehsanarzankar did you got

Answer (score 0):

Below are the code which I am expecting it should work in your case.

as view expect some source value to bind drop down and default it consider there is a viewdata available at controller end.

Controller Code

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
            Person person = new Person();
            person.Firstname = "jinesh";
            person.Lastname = "jain";
            items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = person.FullName, Value = person.FullName });
            ViewData["FullName"] = items;
}

public class Person
        {
            public string Firstname { get; set; }
            public string Lastname { get; set; }
            public string FullName
            {
                get
                {
                    return Firstname + " " + Lastname;
                }
            }
        }
```